# What is the better way send props between screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have to send data another screen. And I need to change the data on the parent screen when data changes on this screen. I tried to set/get params react-native navigation. But it doesn't work for me. What is the better way pass props/state between screen? How can I find out that my data has changed? and how can i store them for next time?

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378127/react-native-pass-data-between-two-components/52379835#52379835

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to pass data from Screen A to Screen B or from a Parent component to a child component you should use props. This is what you are already doing just pass an extra prop which will be a callback function and is defined in the parent component which will update data in parent when some data changes in child component.
2. If you want to pass data to lets say nth screen (i.e from Screen A -> B -> C -> D ). Its better to use React Context.
   You can read about it here 
   https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html